# AWS S3 key suspected fraudulent activity in your AWS account / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I received a notice from AWS S3 that they "suspected fraudulent activity in my AWS account". I was indeed facing an humongous usage of EC2 triggering a bill of several thousands dollars. Upon some research, I realized that this was not an isolated issue (https://pivotedreality.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/amazon-aws-vs-github-suspected-unauthorized-activity/) and I  probably revealed the key when I moved my code from a private bitbucket repository to a public github repository.

I thought though that the access keys was only used to pinpoint object on S3. Could anyone explain to me how exposing the access keys give control over EC2 usage (which seems to be another service). I do not get a clear answer from Amazon. In addition, what is the best practice going forward when using the access keys for S3? I simply put it in my config file (I work with Rails) without imagining so serious consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access keys (including the secret key) for an IAM user are used for accessing the AWS account as that user programatically.

As such, if these are compromised then anyone with access to these keys is able to use those keys to perform any action that that IAM user can do.

AWS scans public repos looking for accidental publishing of keys in people's source code and then blocks that user until the key is revoked to prevent misuse of the account.

To prevent the leaking of keys in source code you can put them into environment variables, use IAM roles on an EC2 instance (allowing the metadata service to give the EC2 instance access to anything that the role provides) or simply make sure your credentials are in a configuration file that is included in your `.gitignore`.